# Update from gradle 0.8 to 0.9

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've updated from Gradle 0.8 to 0.9 but it gives me incompatibility problems. I've tried to fix it but I don't know exactly where the problem is.

A help is really appreciated.. this is my Gradle file :) thanks!

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.2.+'
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:library:2.5.2'
    compile files('libs/TestFlightLib.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The error is something like:

```
 Failed to refresh Gradle project 'gradle'
 Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ResolvedComponentResult'.
 This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.
```

Comment: "it gives me incompatibility problems" such as?

Comment: added in the description, thanks for asking :)

Comment: what gradle version you use?

Comment: Using a plus in library versions is not recommended. Gradle has lint warning about that. It's a good practice to manually check if new version of a library is compatible with your app and then updating the library version in a dependency.

Comment: @DoctororDrive I second Doctoror Drive. Writing 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+' would have caused pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it. For those who are reading, the problem is located in your

gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

file. The file should be similar to this:

```
#Fri Mar 07 11:15:20 CET 2014
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

In particular, you need gradle-1.10 and not gradle-1.9

**If you don't have this file** (that was my case), just create it and rebuild the project. If there are still errors, clean the project and build it again.

Comment: From Google+ (https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/SymhwQYyUUi):
"We've released version 0.9.0 of the Gradle plugin for Android:

It's compatible with Gradle 1.10 and 1.11 (using 1.11 will require Studio 0.5.0 which is not out yet)."

Comment: And you need build tools 19.0.3

Comment: yes indeed.. the problem was that I didn't have the file.. so instead of changing the line, I had to create it!